# GridView - use image as select button, does not fire select event

Tags: asp.net

If I use a button, it works fine, but when I use the template column(commented in code smple) as a custom select button (with an image)  the select event does not work

```
<%-- <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="table-header-repeat line-left">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgSelect" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/arrow_right.png"
            CommandName="Select" Height="32" Width="32" CausesValidation="false"  />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="table-header-repeat line-left" />
    <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
</asp:TemplateField>--%>

<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True"  />
```

Comment: Why do you have comment blocks `<%-- --%>` around the TemplateField?

Comment: Where is the code that handle this command ? and where is the declaration of the GridView ? This is critical to make your command work. (and remove the comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you by any chance using a Master Page?  And does the `ContentPlaceHolder` of the Master Page have ViewState turned off?

This was responsible for the same situation in [this post](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/547875-gridview-rowcommand-not-firing).